# Convert Json to Csv using Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a pdf and generated it to json file. now,  i am trying to convert this json to table format.
Any inputs would be appreciated.
I tried to get the details in JSON and now need to used this as inout to convert to CSV which i'm unable todo through lambda functions

[image]

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "DocumentMetadata": {
      "Pages": 1
    },
    "JobStatus": "SUCCEEDED",
    "Blocks": [
      {
        "BlockType": "PAGE",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 1.0,
            "Height": 1.0,
            "Left": 0.0,
            "Top": 0.0
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.0,
              "Y": 0.0
            },
            {
              "X": 1.0,
              "Y": 0.0
            },
            {
              "X": 1.0,
              "Y": 1.0
            },
            {
              "X": 0.0,
              "Y": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "13c6cafe-f4df-44d6-9ff5-eed1cd780bd2",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "0742a0ff-94b4-4298-9f24-57c347ef7a72",
              "e785a2fc-24ee-44c0-9d95-e8cb18e79c36",
              "73bc3eb3-fb5a-41af-8711-d7c34849743a",
              "d5ab8a3b-f478-4dfd-9eaf-877eaed50610",
              "759f048c-4f0d-4396-b8d9-c7f7389a7407",
              "b52b833f-374c-4676-a97a-cb54bb41c110",
              "6a5e1a2a-a8e6-462a-88a7-ebc080a33057",
              "3a59adf2-dff4-4f1c-b9ca-8966ac900588",
              "5d16f650-406c-4d70-8d85-734ee540088e",
              "d13346a4-df99-45c6-95ef-5b7cad933f02",
              "5a67a4d2-e640-4647-9175-f4622d4c4eb5",
              "2478a7af-3a87-4a53-953d-8e73a0f0b81e",
              "96194314-7c9c-4640-bc2a-fce64947560f",
              "f801a091-7f91-4cd3-972f-4a305ce96ded",
              "7cfff7ae-6e07-4cf0-9093-661cf971382c",
              "7d9c62eb-e576-4cdd-ba6a-10311ace0128",
              "ab845f10-6ed0-4442-819f-073deaabb67f",
              "dc33834f-e653-461e-8be4-6d00ab8ffd53",
              "d16cc96c-5bfa-4716-91fb-ff3ddc121708",
              "928d55a2-88d9-4f53-9fa5-d41f664385bc",
              "28277c5b-927e-45de-8117-4f0974e01dd3",
              "1db50e19-24a1-425b-90c2-cdc219ab0b3d",
              "e30e5f8b-c34c-4b1f-b9ae-0f7538d666dd",
              "1af40413-2bc1-4e3d-94ba-f08e30467da8",
              "bbcedeb6-3aa4-4d49-ac00-68b6f132a499",
              "ee7c5199-ef0e-4786-894b-7ffbf966fe72"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 93.11936950683594,
        "Text": "Jatoba's",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.1433018445968628,
            "Height": 0.03813503682613373,
            "Left": 0.32373523712158203,
            "Top": 0.19060097634792328
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.32373523712158203,
              "Y": 0.19060097634792328
            },
            {
              "X": 0.4670370817184448,
              "Y": 0.19060097634792328
            },
            {
              "X": 0.4670370817184448,
              "Y": 0.228736013174057
            },
            {
              "X": 0.32373523712158203,
              "Y": 0.228736013174057
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "0742a0ff-94b4-4298-9f24-57c347ef7a72",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "2c15bfdc-fa79-4d99-b871-28285373554e"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 90.12268829345703,
        "Text": "Company",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.16724464297294617,
            "Height": 0.045264482498168945,
            "Left": 0.3226318657398224,
            "Top": 0.2500065267086029
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.3226318657398224,
              "Y": 0.2500065267086029
            },
            {
              "X": 0.48987650871276855,
              "Y": 0.2500065267086029
            },
            {
              "X": 0.48987650871276855,
              "Y": 0.29527100920677185
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3226318657398224,
              "Y": 0.29527100920677185
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "e785a2fc-24ee-44c0-9d95-e8cb18e79c36",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "b5997681-c27c-4374-9fcf-bf5502b347a5"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 95.8335189819336,
        "Text": "Employee Schedule Jan 2033",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.15650513768196106,
            "Height": 0.01590380072593689,
            "Left": 0.3232109248638153,
            "Top": 0.30444231629371643
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.3232109248638153,
              "Y": 0.30444231629371643
            },
            {
              "X": 0.47971606254577637,
              "Y": 0.30444231629371643
            },
            {
              "X": 0.47971606254577637,
              "Y": 0.3203461170196533
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3232109248638153,
              "Y": 0.3203461170196533
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "73bc3eb3-fb5a-41af-8711-d7c34849743a",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "3e825389-d3fb-4ec5-b43c-993b94970864",
              "c848beee-8b99-44b8-b26c-c274d7ecbc0a",
              "705db34a-808d-4e37-afc8-db57d275f0a2",
              "c52d0665-b8bf-4a5f-88cb-defa68142e51"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.88838195800781,
        "Text": "Employee Wage Overview",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.14624851942062378,
            "Height": 0.016500651836395264,
            "Left": 0.32340535521507263,
            "Top": 0.40369004011154175
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.32340535521507263,
              "Y": 0.40369004011154175
            },
            {
              "X": 0.4696538746356964,
              "Y": 0.40369004011154175
            },
            {
              "X": 0.4696538746356964,
              "Y": 0.420190691947937
            },
            {
              "X": 0.32340535521507263,
              "Y": 0.420190691947937
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "d5ab8a3b-f478-4dfd-9eaf-877eaed50610",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "4f887a49-9f8f-4cf7-85af-9439ad8713a8",
              "eef4e98b-86c4-4a88-b4d0-2ea146f8fe46",
              "cc757c31-200b-4163-b8d6-ada0e9f39d38"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.39978790283203,
        "Text": "Employee's Name",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.0956905260682106,
            "Height": 0.016250843182206154,
            "Left": 0.3672836124897003,
            "Top": 0.4652557671070099
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.3672836124897003,
              "Y": 0.4652557671070099
            },
            {
              "X": 0.4629741311073303,
              "Y": 0.4652557671070099
            },
            {
              "X": 0.4629741311073303,
              "Y": 0.4815066158771515
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3672836124897003,
              "Y": 0.4815066158771515
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "759f048c-4f0d-4396-b8d9-c7f7389a7407",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "e51cf007-3bf0-4617-9442-bf6806189fed",
              "a7a104d6-e081-4bad-9f92-f0aefa93d681"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 98.95868682861328,
        "Text": "Shift",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.02570188045501709,
            "Height": 0.013512402772903442,
            "Left": 0.5692687034606934,
            "Top": 0.4651762545108795
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.5692687034606934,
              "Y": 0.4651762545108795
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5949705839157104,
              "Y": 0.4651762545108795
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5949705839157104,
              "Y": 0.47868865728378296
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5692687034606934,
              "Y": 0.47868865728378296
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "b52b833f-374c-4676-a97a-cb54bb41c110",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "237e517d-2fd3-4d79-8b7e-03897e60407a"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.03609466552734,
        "Text": "Monthly wage",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.07680517435073853,
            "Height": 0.016166359186172485,
            "Left": 0.6586208939552307,
            "Top": 0.46529674530029297
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.6586208939552307,
              "Y": 0.46529674530029297
            },
            {
              "X": 0.7354260683059692,
              "Y": 0.46529674530029297
            },
            {
              "X": 0.7354260683059692,
              "Y": 0.48146310448646545
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6586208939552307,
              "Y": 0.48146310448646545
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "6a5e1a2a-a8e6-462a-88a7-ebc080a33057",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "f3355d88-40ec-4839-b321-81cf442b9779",
              "deca4857-07de-4c8a-aa87-3672bcc2e1b3"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.92090606689453,
        "Text": "A",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.00935131311416626,
            "Height": 0.012871384620666504,
            "Left": 0.5277141332626343,
            "Top": 0.5084642767906189
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.5277141332626343,
              "Y": 0.5084642767906189
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5370654463768005,
              "Y": 0.5084642767906189
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5370654463768005,
              "Y": 0.5213356614112854
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5277141332626343,
              "Y": 0.5213356614112854
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "3a59adf2-dff4-4f1c-b9ca-8966ac900588",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "5d21ab13-210e-44e4-b841-e7e441490697"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.94129180908203,
        "Text": "B",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.007892727851867676,
            "Height": 0.01409977674484253,
            "Left": 0.5770425796508789,
            "Top": 0.507464587688446
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.5770425796508789,
              "Y": 0.507464587688446
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5849353075027466,
              "Y": 0.507464587688446
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5849353075027466,
              "Y": 0.5215643644332886
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5770425796508789,
              "Y": 0.5215643644332886
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "5d16f650-406c-4d70-8d85-734ee540088e",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "505f5721-9d3c-4046-a367-0274a6ba0a87"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 98.0021743774414,
        "Text": "C",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.008314788341522217,
            "Height": 0.012576639652252197,
            "Left": 0.6265605688095093,
            "Top": 0.5085314512252808
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.6265605688095093,
              "Y": 0.5085314512252808
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6348753571510315,
              "Y": 0.5085314512252808
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6348753571510315,
              "Y": 0.521108090877533
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6265605688095093,
              "Y": 0.521108090877533
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "d13346a4-df99-45c6-95ef-5b7cad933f02",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "a15b5f17-d639-4654-99bf-80f03eb0d9d8"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.90572357177734,
        "Text": "Name",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.032360732555389404,
            "Height": 0.01297903060913086,
            "Left": 0.3236062228679657,
            "Top": 0.5450003147125244
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.3236062228679657,
              "Y": 0.5450003147125244
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3559669554233551,
              "Y": 0.5450003147125244
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3559669554233551,
              "Y": 0.5579793453216553
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3236062228679657,
              "Y": 0.5579793453216553
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "5a67a4d2-e640-4647-9175-f4622d4c4eb5",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "2f91dfe6-93c4-4fea-bd8a-8209bb4a4224"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.79938507080078,
        "Text": "Elon Musk",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.05537908896803856,
            "Height": 0.013659536838531494,
            "Left": 0.323792427778244,
            "Top": 0.5813485980033875
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.323792427778244,
              "Y": 0.5813485980033875
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3791715204715729,
              "Y": 0.5813485980033875
            },
            {
              "X": 0.3791715204715729,
              "Y": 0.595008134841919
            },
            {
              "X": 0.323792427778244,
              "Y": 0.595008134841919
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "2478a7af-3a87-4a53-953d-8e73a0f0b81e",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "15cc80b5-fc77-4e94-904e-cdb0e6dfc7b8",
              "3f6329df-7163-49c5-99fb-74ae07af1308"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 96.1291732788086,
        "Text": "2",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.006891846656799316,
            "Height": 0.012587487697601318,
            "Left": 0.5290947556495667,
            "Top": 0.5821124315261841
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.5290947556495667,
              "Y": 0.5821124315261841
            },
            {
              "X": 0.535986602306366,
              "Y": 0.5821124315261841
            },
            {
              "X": 0.535986602306366,
              "Y": 0.5946999192237854
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5290947556495667,
              "Y": 0.5946999192237854
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "96194314-7c9c-4640-bc2a-fce64947560f",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "0440cd1c-365a-456b-a0e5-022173861cda"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.98282623291016,
        "Text": "3",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.006731271743774414,
            "Height": 0.012602508068084717,
            "Left": 0.5775370597839355,
            "Top": 0.582022488117218
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.5775370597839355,
              "Y": 0.582022488117218
            },
            {
              "X": 0.58426833152771,
              "Y": 0.582022488117218
            },
            {
              "X": 0.58426833152771,
              "Y": 0.5946249961853027
            },
            {
              "X": 0.5775370597839355,
              "Y": 0.5946249961853027
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "f801a091-7f91-4cd3-972f-4a305ce96ded",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "3c36d5de-cdec-468f-a35c-b0bbc6399395"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.98986053466797,
        "Text": "5",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.00619131326675415,
            "Height": 0.012855708599090576,
            "Left": 0.6278905272483826,
            "Top": 0.5819470286369324
          },
          "Polygon": [
            {
              "X": 0.6278905272483826,
              "Y": 0.5819470286369324
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6340818405151367,
              "Y": 0.5819470286369324
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6340818405151367,
              "Y": 0.594802737236023
            },
            {
              "X": 0.6278905272483826,
              "Y": 0.594802737236023
            }
          ]
        },
        "Id": "7cfff7ae-6e07-4cf0-9093-661cf971382c",
        "Relationships": [
          {
            "Type": "CHILD",
            "Ids": [
              "e0e848a8-2e3e-40b2-8dd7-ef4f58c679de"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "Page": 1
      },
      {
        "BlockType": "LINE",
        "Confidence": 99.96109771728516,
        "Text": "10",
        "Geometry": {
          "BoundingBox": {
            "Width": 0.013098657131195068,
            "Height": 0.01290583610534668,
            "Left": 0.691054105758667,
            "Top": 0.5818639397621155
          },
```

I'm a beginner and trying the possibilites, any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show us some code? AWS Lambda ist not a programming language.

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)